# Replacing abbreviations from dictionary

Tags: python, regex, csv, dictionary, replace

I have a question similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856001/replace-with-abbreviations-from-dictionary-using-python). But I have an additional question. Taking the same table from that question below, I added a couple of additional rows.

```
A,B,C,D
RNA,lung cancer,15,biotin
RNA,lung cancer,15,biotin
RNA,breast cancer,15,biotin
RNA,breast cancer,15,biotin
RNA,lung cancer,15,biotin
65 y 4m,prostate cancer,biotin
m,lung cancer,biotin
```

Quoting the same sample dictionary with three additional lines

```
rna,ribonucleic acid
rnd,radical neck dissection
rni,recommended nutrient intake
rnp,ribonucleoprotein
m,months
m,male
y,years
```

I'd like to replace it logically, for example, a number followed by m (with or without space between the number and letter 'm', similarly with 'y' year) would be months, whereas character followed by m or a single m would be male (and not month because m for month occurs first in the dictionary). I want my final output to be

```
A,B,C,D
ribonucleic acid,lung cancer,15,biotin
ribonucleic acid,lung cancer,15,biotin
ribonucleic acid,breast cancer,15,biotin
ribonucleic acid,breast cancer,15,biotin
ribonucleic acid,lung cancer,15,biotin
65 years 4months,prostate cancer,biotin
male,lung cancer,biotin
```

Comment: To distinguish one "m" (month) from the other "m" (male) is quite difficult.

Comment: @snotna I'm positive, it can be done using regex, which I'm really bad at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each substitution that you want to make, define a pattern and a substituting string. Make the pattern capture the text that comes immediately before the text to be substituted. You can use that text when you make the substitution. Like this:

```
import re

month_pair = (re.compile('(\d\s*)m'), 'months')
year_pair = (re.compile('(\d\s*)y'), 'years')

def substitute(s, pairs):
  for (pattern, substitution) in pairs:
    match = pattern.search(s)
    if match:
      s = pattern.sub(match.group(1)+substitution, s)
  return s

pairs = [month_pair, year_pair]
print(substitute('65 y 4m', pairs))
```